# Unable to mock Queue object (in C#)

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, moq, xunit

I am trying to mock a Queue Object (using MOQ framework) but getting the following error,

System.NotSupportedException: 'Unsupported expression: x => x.Enqueue(It.IsAny())
Non-overridable members (here: Queue.Enqueue) may not be used in setup / verification expressions.'

(Attached the screenshot as well)

Following section contains my code,

```
public class ISampleData
{
    int ID { get; set; }

    double Data { get; set; }
}

public class SampleData: ISampleData
{
    public int ID { get; set; }

    public double Data { get; set; }
}

public class DataManager
{
    private Queue<ISampleData> dataQueue;

    public DataManager(Queue<ISampleData> dataQueue)
    {
        this.dataQueue = dataQueue;
    }

    public bool InsertData(ISampleData sampleData)
    {
        bool flag = false;
        try
        {
            this.dataQueue.Enqueue(sampleData);
            flag = true;
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            flag = false;
        }

        return flag;
    }

}
```

And following section contains the test method,

```
/// <summary>
/// Testing Enqueue method with exception.
/// </summary>
[Fact]
public void Test_EnqueueMethod_With_Exception()
{
    // Arrange
    Mock<Queue<ISampleData>> mockQueue = new Mock<Queue<ISampleData>>();
    DataManager dataManager = new DataManager(mockQueue.Object);

    mockQueue.Setup(x => x.Enqueue(It.IsAny<ISampleData>())).Throws(new Exception());

    // Act
    var actual = dataManager.InsertData(new SampleData() { ID = 1001, Data = 20.9876 });

    // Assert
    Assert.False(actual);
}
```

Want to understand are we getting this error and how to mitigate the same.

Comment: Just as the error says. To mock something it must be able to be overwritten like an Interface method or a virtual method or abstract method. Queue.Enqueue just isn't.

Comment: I don't see why you would mock the Queue inside your DataManager

Comment: @Ralf Does that mean, I'll not be able to mock Queue objects? In that case, what else can I use? I mean, instead of Queue what should I use then, so that I can properly test my code, as well?

Comment: Why are you trying to mock such a basic container? That's like trying to mock a List<T> or array. In fact, a Queue is often used as mock storage for advanced queueing services .... although it's a bit too low level even for that

Comment: @TheKingmaker testing doesn't mean you have to mock every type.

Comment: @MateusZampol This is just sample code, I have posted. In DataManager class, I want to take care of the scenario, when Queue object throws exception. Want to write unit test case on DataManager regarding the same.

Comment: You don't need to mock Queue then. Just use a new empty queue in every test. Mocking is used to replace things that are hard to test. A Queue isn't hard to test.

Comment: Then maybe come up with a better example why you need that Enqueue isn't event documented to throw exceptions. It would be something in the OutOfMemory area and then you will have additional problems in the surrounding code. So a pretty useless test.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Actually, its just a sample code, I have posted. In actual application I have something much bigger code. Just want to make sure that my DataManager performs appropriate action if Queue object breaks or encounters some exceptions.

Comment: Typically you surround those things that aren't directly testable with a slim wrapper to resurface those methods and be mockable. But as far as i see it Queue is in the "it isn't worth it" region. That means using the wrapper everywhere in your code and the actual class never directly.

Answer (score 2):

You should be testing the "interface" of your class rather than any implementation details. So what is the "interface"? What are the possible return values of `InsertData`?

If you take a look at the [Queue.Enqueue](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.queue-1.enqueue?view=net-8.0) documentation you can see that there are no documented exceptions. Since this is a builtin .net collection you can be fairly sure that the documentation is accurate. If it was a third party class it *might* be useful with a unit test that confirms that the object conforms to your expectations, but that would be better implemented as a unit test of the *queue*.

This does not necessarily mean that the collection may never throw an exception, but the kind of exceptions that could be thrown are exceptions that cannot be meaningfully handled. If you get an Out of Memory error or a Stack Overflow error you should be crashing the process as soon as possible, not try to catch it and carry on. So your idea of testing if the queue throw exception will provide very little, if any, value.

You could change your class to depend on an custom `IQueue` interface instead of a concrete implementation. This would allow it to be mocked. But this would only be meaningful if you can provide different implementations that still conform to the same interface. This is useful when trying to represent something like a database, but it is typically not useful for simple collections.

Unit testing does not mean testing classes in isolation, but rather "units" of functionality. That might be a class, but it could just as well be a single method, or some arbitrary large collection of classes. The important part is that there is a well defined interface to test against. Your queue should likely be considered an implementation detail, and therefore part of the same "unit".

Also keep in mind that you should test things that provide *value*. Writing overly detailed test can be just as harmful as no tests, since your unit tests will break for perfectly valid changes.